# Avoid re triggering a function due to a param in URL history

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application, the `href` are created by a common directive. In a particular use case, I need to show a notification when the page pointed by specific `href` in opened.

For this, I added `onClick` to `a` tag.

```
<a create-link="nextDocument" data-ng-click="appendParamToHref($event)">
```

The `onClick` js function:

```
$scope.appendParamToHref = function (event) {
   event.currentTarget.href += '&appendedParam=true';
};
```

I read the new param `appendedParam` in my controller when the new page loads, show the notification and everything works fine.

**The Problem:**

Since the new param -`appendedParam`, is added to URL, it's stored in browser history when the user navigates to another URL. When the user comes back to the URL where `appendedParam` is stored, notification is shown again. This was not the expected behavior.

What alternative approach can I use to avoid this scenario?

Comment: Are you using ng-router or ui-router?

Comment: I use `angular-ui-router`

Comment: and I read url param in my controller using `$location.search().appendedParam;`

Comment: Any feedback or suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle your PopUp triggers not by adding an URL parameter to avoid your problem. Instead you could make use of `$rootScope` and handle your PopUp event on that way:

#### View

```
<a create-link="nextDocument" data-ng-click="setPopup('popUpType')">Some link</a>
```

#### Controller scope function

```
$scope.setPopup = function (nameOfPopUp) {
    $rootScope.popUpToOpen = nameOfPopUp;
};
```

#### ui-router `$stateChangeSucess` listener is called after a route has changed

Once the route changed you can check if a PopUp to open was set before. It will open once and reset automatically by a simple trigger reset handling.

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
     if (angular.isDefined($rootScope.popUpToOpen) && $rootScope.popUpToOpen !== null) {
         switch ($rootScope.popUpToOpen) {

             case 'popUpType':
                 //open popup logic here
                 break;
         }

         //unset popup after it was displayed once
         $rootScope.popUpToOpen = null;
     }
});
```

Comment: +1 , Though this is will work, I wanted to avoid writing a new `stateChangeSuccess`, this will be called every time unnecessarily. I had a similar solution in my mind using my `services`.

Comment: @ArshadRehmani It realy doesnt matter that it is called every time the state changed. This little code snipped does not effect your performance at all. A service would much more than this. And also your service would be called, injected, executed "every-time" -> this would be much more as using the default listener  `$stateChangeSucess`. Please suggest this and give some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think of solutions in my mind.

**Solution 1:**

Show the notification message after some `timeout`. This tricks `href` to execute 1st and then shows the notification.

```
<a create-link="nextDocument" data-ng-click="showNotification()"></a>
```

JS code:

```
$scope.showNotification = function () { 
    $timeout(function () {
        //show notification code here.
    }, 1000);
};
```

**Solution 2:**

Use a custom `flag` variable from my service.

```
<a create-link="nextDocument" data-ng-click="showNotificationUsingService()"></a>
```

JS code:

```
$scope.showNotificationUsingService= function () {    
    myService.showNotification = true;
};
```

In Controller:

```
if (myService.showNotification) {
  //code to show notification.

  myService.showNotification = false;
}
```

Comment: How does this trigger a popup after pageload?

Comment: In **Case 1**, `href` executes and thus page loads, after 1 second, code to show notification is called.(assuming page got loaded within 1 second, which is true in my case)

Comment: In **Case 2**, I just set a variable in a common `service`. This variable is read by the `controller` that gets called on new page load. The `controller` uses this variable to show notification.

Comment: This is not neat. You need to ensure that the stage change has proceeded. Timeouts are not a good idea at all. You should avoid them because they are related to the client performance. You should use `state`, `events`, `callbacks` everytime to ensure a `state`, e.g. has been changed successfully/proceeded. Thats why it would be much better to use the `stateChangeSuccess` callback, which is a neat solution. You realy should avoid using timeouts in such state logics.

Comment: @lin What about my 2nd solution?

Comment: Yea, that could work. But I would preffer to have a service injected only in one point inside your application instead injecting it in all controller where its needed (global service). I realy think my solution based on KISS is more valuable because its a simple implementation for that kind of logic. It delivers a global handling for the application in a simple way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137400/discussion-between-arshad-rehmani-and-lin).